# check for variable existence with isset?

Tags: php, arrays, var, isset

ok this is very strange, i tried over and over using different methods but nothin seems to work for what I need.

I have a `description.txt` file with contents in form of:

`filename|title|description`

now, for each line of that file I do:

```
            $parts = explode('|', $line);

            $this->info[$parts[0]]['title'] = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : 'no-title';
            $this->info[$parts[0]]['description'] = isset($parts[2]) ? $parts[2] : 'no-description';
```

however, because some of lines in my `description.txt` file do not have title & description, but filename only
I thought that checking for existence of those missing parts will do, and in that case echo `no-title` and `no-description`
respectively. But the code above does not yield those strings, and I don't see anything echoed out.

I tried with `array_key_exists('1', $parts)` also, without success. Tried with `is_null` without success. 
I don't have any ideas why this doesn't work.

Just to add, code is working fine if none of the pipe delimited parts is missing, so it's just a problem of how to catch those non-existing.

Doing `var_dump` on `$parts[1]`, for lines that do not have anything after filename gives me `null`

This is output of `var_dump($parts); die;` if first line is filename only:

```
array (size=1)
0 => string '10172608_1425353644382351_9063428062883749844_n.jpg
' (length=52)
```

Like for example on the first line:

```
filename
filename|title|description
```

I managed to make it work with `!empty($parts[1])` check, but then I have to have in my `description.txt` file:

`filename|||` for it to work, and I would like to skip those extra pipes when I don't have title or description.

HERE IS THE ENTIRE LOOP:
This works if `description.txt` file is like:

```
    filename|||
```

for lines that do not contain title or description.

```
    if($handle = @fopen($this->path . "/" . $this->desc_file, "r")) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

            // process each line and put title & desc into an info array
            $parts = explode('|', $line);

            $this->info[$parts[0]]['title'] = ! empty($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : 'no-title';
            $this->info[$parts[0]]['description'] = ! empty($parts[2]) ? $parts[2] : 'no-description';
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you tried to print your `$parts` to see what you have inside?

Comment: @ThiagoFrança see my edit for var_dump output

Comment: paste the entire code with the loop.

Comment: I don't see errors on the code... only to test, change `$line = fgets...` to `$line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|')`. `fgetcsv` returns an array and you needn't take a `explode`.

Comment: sorry, the issue was linefeeds on the input. just trim those off and it makes a lot more sense. I have updated the answer with the new code.

Comment: I will check this tonight when I get home, and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @ryan vincent it was a linefeed issue, thanks, it works now as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim the lines that are read from the file as they have linefeed characters on them.

I also stored all the details in the 'info' array...

```
    if ($handle = fopen(__DIR__ ."/description.txt", "r")) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $line = trim($line);
        // process each line and put title & desc into an info array
        $parts = explode('|', $line);

        $fileDetails = array();
        $fileDetails['filename'] = ! empty($parts[0]) ? $parts[0] : 'no-filename';
        $fileDetails['title'] = ! empty($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : 'no-title';
        $fileDetails['description'] = ! empty($parts[2]) ? $parts[2] : 'no-description';

        $this->info[] = $fileDetails;
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: this works, but why can't I simply check for null, if var_dump is telling me that $parts[1] is null, in those cases where I have only the filename?

Comment: @branquito, if you do a count of the array you will see that there are not always three parts supplied from the 'explode'. so you have to use 'isset' or 'empty' checks. array_shift **always** returns a result. it is null when there are no more entries in the array.

Comment: var_dump -ing is fine, however when I use $title and $description variables in my ternary check still not getting `no-title` or `no-description`

Comment: @branquito, you are aware the array is not $part[0]['title']'? if all items are there it will be $part[0], $part[1] and $part[2].

Comment: it's not `$part[0]['title']`, it is `info[$part[0]]['title']`, that's another array

Comment: @branquito, the check you are doing with the 'isset' and '!empty' look fine to me. they should be working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52139/discussion-between-branquito-and-ryan-vincent)

Answer (score 0):

check - it helps

```
$parts = explode('|', $line);

$no_title = 'no-title';
if($parts[1]){
  $no_title = $parts[1];
}

$no_description = 'no-description';

if($parts[2]){
  $no_description = $parts[2];
}

$this->info[$parts[0]]['title'] = $no_title;
$this->info[$parts[0]]['description'] = $no_description;
```

for example

```
$line =  'filename';

$no_title = 'no-title';
if($parts[1]){
  $no_title = $parts[1];
}

$no_description = 'no-description';

if($parts[2]){
  $no_description = $parts[2];
}

echo $no_title .' ';
echo $no_description;
```

Output:

```
no-title no-description
```

Comment: that seems overcomplicating to me, I would like to know why can't I check for variable exsistence with isset(), if I only have $parts[0], like var_dump says, I just want to check if $parts[1] exists, and it does not, so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at size of array [function.count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
$parts = explode('|', $line);
$this->info[$parts[0]]['title'] = count($parts)==1 : 'no-title';
$this->info[$parts[0]]['description'] = count($parts)==2 : 'no-description';
```

Comment: if you are checking `isset(parts[1])` `count(parts)` must be 2 
i don't know other way